# How to seperate fixed width length text by a delimeter based on set characters?

Tags: file, hadoop, data-structures, cloudera, file-format

I have the following 30 character fixed width length series ID in a text file which I would like to separate by a delimiter/put in separate columns. I have thousands of ID’s in this file. The file itself is over 2 GB - I am using EmEditor to view the file:

For instance the series ID “NWU371674020200000000002505000”
Needs to be converted into 
NWU,37,16740,2,02,0000,000000,25,05,00,0

The separation always follows the same separation pattern by characters:
NWU (3 character lengths)
37 (2 character lengths)
16740 (5 character lengths)
2 (1 character lengths)
02 (2 character lengths)
0000 (4 character lengths) 
000000 (6 character lengths)
25 (2 character lengths) 
05 (2 character lengths)
00 (2 character lengths)
0 (1 character lengths)

Any ideas on how to do this with such a large file? Preferably without code? Or using a programming language that would easy to code with this?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is this a one time task or you will need to do this periodically?

Comment: One time ask. For one large text file.